# How can I combine Outlook email for easier documentation?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have been asked to send someone all emails relating to a certain issue (let's say planning a dog show), to document how it evolved over time. So, there are 50+ Outlook emails to/from different people. I'd like to group them into a single document and be able to add comments to each, for example "Here Frank suggested eliminating the Doberman pincher competition." What is a sensible way to do this? One idea is to make a Word document and insert the emails with captions, but let me know if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the emails you want to be documented, go up to file, choose "save as", and then set the "Save as type" option to "Text Only (.txt)". This will create a .txt file that will display the emails in the order your inbox sorted them (you may want to try sorting from oldest to newest to make more sense). Hopefully this helps!